How can I count the value of previous rows until criterion is reached?
I have a dataset, where each row indicates one correct/wrong interaction of a participant. I would like to count the number of wrong interactions, until the participant has logged a correct answer twice.
My dataframe looks like this:
id = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3)
accuracy = c(0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1)
timestamp = c(2405.078,2409.575,2414.239,2419.084,2424.138,2428.510,805.5845,812.2674,817.6420,822.5424,828.0416,832.9703,842.2013,456.9943,463.0222,469.0649,475.2177,480.3976,486.9402,491.5632,497.0068)

df <-data.frame(id, accuracy, timestamp)

I was thinking of using the rle function, but I am not sure how to add the condition. I would need to create a new variable, the gives me the trial count until condition is met.
It should look something like this:



ID
trial_count




1
5


2
5


3
4



Ideally I would then add another column that calculates the time spent until condition is reached with the timestamps.
Thanks for the help!

Another approach using cumsum within each group. This will use slice to keep rows until sum of 2 for accuracy is reached. Then in reframe will count up the number of rows and calculate time difference for each id. The result will vary if less than 2 accuracy (unclear what output should be in this case, if it is possible). Also, to count wrong answers until 2 correct is reached, can subtract 2 from number of rows.
library(tidyverse)

df |>
  slice(
    seq_len(which.max(cumsum(accuracy) >= 2)),
    .by = id
  ) |>
  reframe(
    trial_count = n(),
    time_spent = last(timestamp) - first(timestamp),
    .by = id
  )

Or with older version of tidyverse packages:
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  slice(seq_len(which.max(cumsum(accuracy) >= 2))) %>%
  summarise(
    trial_count = n(),
    time_spent = last(timestamp) - first(timestamp)
  )

Output
  id trial_count time_spent
1  1           5    19.0600
2  2           5    22.4571
3  3           7    34.5689


Thank you! I don't have the newest r version installed, I exchanged |> with %>%. It does give me the message that it can't find the function "reframe" even though I load dplyr and tidyverse. Do you think it has to do with the update?

@caeco See edited answer, and try with summarise and group_by as above, without the native pipe. Does that work?

I'd do this initially:
df |> dplyr::mutate(tworight = cumsum(accuracy) >1,
                    time_to_tworight = min(timestamp[tworight]) - min(timestamp),
                    wrongs_til_tworight = min(cumsum(accuracy == 0)[tworight]),
                    .by = id)

gives:
   id accuracy timestamp tworight time_to_tworight wrongs_til_tworight
1   1        0 2405.0780    FALSE          19.0600                   3
2   1        1 2409.5750    FALSE          19.0600                   3
3   1        0 2414.2390    FALSE          19.0600                   3
4   1        0 2419.0840    FALSE          19.0600                   3
5   1        1 2424.1380     TRUE          19.0600                   3
6   1        1 2428.5100     TRUE          19.0600                   3
7   2        1  805.5845    FALSE          22.4571                   3
8   2        0  812.2674    FALSE          22.4571                   3
9   2        0  817.6420    FALSE          22.4571                   3
10  2        0  822.5424    FALSE          22.4571                   3
11  2        1  828.0416     TRUE          22.4571                   3
12  2        1  832.9703     TRUE          22.4571                   3
13  2        1  842.2013     TRUE          22.4571                   3
14  3        0  456.9943    FALSE          34.5689                   5
15  3        0  463.0222    FALSE          34.5689                   5
16  3        0  469.0649    FALSE          34.5689                   5
17  3        0  475.2177    FALSE          34.5689                   5
18  3        0  480.3976    FALSE          34.5689                   5
19  3        1  486.9402    FALSE          34.5689                   5
20  3        1  491.5632     TRUE          34.5689                   5
21  3        1  497.0068     TRUE          34.5689                   5


Hi, thank you! It helps with calculating the time, but my main issue is coming up with a condition, where it counts the rows until the value TRUE was logged twice per ID . Do you have any suggestion how I could do that?

@caeco - updated with row number
